# find value from normal dsitribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Random variable Z follows standard normal distribution, random variable X is normal distribution with $N (7.5, 10^2)$ where $P (Z> 1.960)=0.025$
and $P (Z> 1.645) = 0.05$
I`m not sure especially for a and b

i need to find:

a. $P(|z|>1.96)$

by definition of absolute function, $P(z \ge 1.96 or p \le -1.96) =2 *0.025=0.05$

b.$P(x>a)=0.025$

$P(\frac{x-7.5}{10}>\frac{a-7.5}{10})=0.025$

we know that z for 0.025 is 1.96

therefore, $1.96= \frac{a-7.5}{10}$

$19.6+7.5=a$

$a=27.1$

c.$P(x<23.95)$
= $1- p(\frac{x-7.5}{10} \ge \frac{23.95-7.5}{10})$=$ 1- 0.05=0.95$

this looks simple, but i dont want to miss important step

Comment: Your solution is right.

Comment: @NCh thankyou so much!!